# How to avoid Gerrit to automatically add authors as reviewers?

Tags: gerrit

I would like to push a series of patches that contain multiple "Singed-off-by" fields in their commit messages to Gerrit.
The problem is that Gerrit will automatically send e-mail to these authors and add them as reviewers. This is true because some of them are in my company directory, but I don't want to notify them because they are not working on the same project.

This series is a back-port of a full driver from the latest Linux kernel, so I don't want to remove any "Signed-off-by".

Here are the tracks I have explored for the moment:

1. **git push remote HEAD:refs/for/master%notify=NONE**
   This is supposed to push the changes without notifying anyone, but I got the following error message:

> ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master%notify=NONE ("--notify"
>   is not a valid option)

--> I found this option in [Gerrit documentation Version 2.12.2](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#_git_push) and I am using Gerrit v2.8.5, so I guess this option has been removed now.

2. **git push remote HEAD:refs/for/master%r=NONE,cc=NONE**
   But these two options only take email addresses as parameters.
3. **Editing project.config**
   I found many ways to edit this file to automatically add specific reviewers, such as using [plugin "reviewers"], but all I could find was to add reviewers, not to REMOVE automatic reviewers.

Would you have any clue on how to prevent Gerrit to automatically add these reviewer who are in "Signed-off-by" ?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I didn't know Gerrit automatically adds "Signed-off-by" users as reviewers. Are you sure it does it? Or is there some mechanism in place (hook, plugin, etc) to work this out?

Comment: As far as I can see, no such hook is doing it. Here are the hooks that are in use in my git repository:

`$ ls .git/hooks
applypatch-msg.sample  post-update.sample     prepare-commit-msg.sample  update.sample
checkscore.py          pre-applypatch.sample  pre-push
commit-msg             pre-auto-gc            pre-push.sample
commit-msg.sample      pre-commit.sample      pre-rebase.sample`

I think these are quite generic hooks and I could not find anything related to author or "Signed-off-by" in them.

Comment: FYI: all *.sample hooks are disabled (just samples). Anyway, I'm talking about hooks/plugins/scripts running in the Gerrit server not in your local repository.